# How to display name of the card?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I made this game in angular that display pictures of cards but I want to also display their names on the screen but I don't know how. Sometimes it shows the same name for all the cards or not the right name.

This is my TypeScript class Paquet, I tried a lot of ways to display the name but no success

```js
 creationPaquet() {        
        for (let sor in this.sorte) {
            for (let val in this.valeur) {

                // here I display the image
                this.paquet.push("assets/images/" + this.sorte[sor] + "_" + this.valeur[val] + ".gif");

                // here I try to display the name in the console but I want to display it on the screen
                if (this.sorte[sor] === this.sorte[0] && this.valeur[val] === this.valeur[0]) {
                    console.log("2 de pique");
                }       
            }
        }

        this.brasser();
        return this.paquet.pop();
    }
```

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in stackblitz.com which is easy to find out your issue?

Comment: Why not  use arrays, rather than objects with pseudo-numeric keys?

Comment: because I need to transform the names into number so I can use them to rank the cards to do math so I can calculate the best hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a interface that should contain image location and card name like this:

```
interface Card {
  name: string;
  location: string;
}
```

Then strongly type your `paquet` collection and fill it like this:

```
  paquet: Card[] = [];

  public creationPaquet() {
    for (let sor in this.sorte) {
      for (let val in this.valeur) {
        this.paquet.push({
          // construct the name as you need
          name: `${val} de ${sor}`,
          location: "assets/images/" + this.sorte[sor] + "_" + this.valeur[val] + ".gif"
        });
      }
    }
    this.brasser();

    // pop entire object
    return this.paquet.pop();
    // pop only the location
    return this.paquet.pop().location;
  }
```

Note you can return the entire object including the `name` and `location`, or only the `location` depending on your needs.

Comment: interface Card is a class? @wnvko

Comment: @Ray you can use class or interface. I prefer interface as they disappear when Typescript is transpiled to JS.

Comment: ohh ok I never used interface

Comment: i tried the code it works but  i cant do 2 return, the seconde one the return this.paquet.pop().location is fading

Comment: you should chose one. I do not know what you need to be returned from your method. You should either return a card, which has name and location, or card.location - not both.